# Prevent pyramid with chaining multiple observable only when if it's complete

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I use rxjs and my question is, is there any way if i want to call next function only if the observable completed? So instead of this:

```
this.Start(data).subscribe(
    (data) => {
        console.log('next');
    },
    (err) => {
        console.log('err');
    },
    () => {
        console.log('complete');

        this.nextFunction()   // this return with other observable
        .subscribe(
            (data) => {
                console.log('next');
            },
            (err) => {
                console.log('err');
            },
            () => {
                console.log('complete');
                this.nextFunction2(); // this returns with other observable
                .subscribe(
                    (data) => {
                        console.log('next');
                    },
                    (err) => {
                        console.log('err');
                    },
                    () => {
                        console.log('complete');
                        this.nextFunction3()
                        .subscribe(...)
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
);
```

something like this:

```
this.Start(data).subscribe(
    (data) => {
        console.log('next');
    },
    (err) => {
        console.log('err');
    },
    () => {
        console.log('complete');
        return other observable;
    }
)
.then(
    (data) => {
        console.log('next');
    },
    (err) => {
        console.log('err');
    },
    () => {
        console.log('complete');
        return other observable;
    }
)
.then(
    (data) => {
        console.log('next');
    },
    (err) => {
        console.log('err');
    },
    () => {
        console.log('complete');
        return other observable;
    }
);
```

So i don't want to design my code like a pyramid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the static [`concat`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-concat) operator to compose an observable that subscribes to the observables one after the other:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/concat';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/defer';

Observable.concat(
  this.Start(data),
  Observable.defer(() => this.nextFunction()),
  Observable.defer(() => this.nextFunction2()),
  Observable.defer(() => this.nextFunction3()),
)
.subscribe();
```

Note that the [`defer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer) operator is used to defer the calls that obtain subquent observables.

With some logging composed in:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/concat';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/defer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

Observable.concat(
  this.Start(data).do(
    (value) => { console.log("next: Start:", value); },
    (error) => { console.log("error: Start:", error); },
    () => { console.log("completed: Start"); }
  ),
  Observable.defer(() => this.nextFunction().do(
    (value) => { console.log("next: nextFunction:", value); },
    (error) => { console.log("error: nextFunction:", error); },
    () => { console.log("completed: nextFunction"); }
  )),
  Observable.defer(() => this.nextFunction2().do(
    (value) => { console.log("next: nextFunction2:", value); },
    (error) => { console.log("error: nextFunction2:", error); },
    () => { console.log("completed: nextFunction2"); }
  )),
  Observable.defer(() => this.nextFunction3().do(
    (value) => { console.log("next: nextFunction3:", value); },
    (error) => { console.log("error: nextFunction3:", error); },
    () => { console.log("completed: nextFunction3"); }
  )),
)
.subscribe();
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! I use with concat instead concatMap, because second one not exist for me.

Comment: Yep. `concatMap` was a typo.

Comment: I tried out, what happen if an error occurred observer.error('hups'); I use this in the start function and i got on my console this: "error: Start: hups" and the dispose run as it had to, but after this the app crashed with the following message: throw sink.syncErrorValue; and that's all.

How i should handle this exception to not kill the app, just break the chain?

Comment: Handle it via the `error` function that's passed to `subscribe` (after the `next` function)